# nginx URL rewrite for subfolders

Tags: nginx, magento

I have 2 subfolders, they are opened on my_url/test1 and my_url/test2

```
location /test1 {
    index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test1 /index.php;
    expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
}

location /test2 {
    index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test2/index.php;
    expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
}
```

I want to add 3 additional test subfolders (test3, test4, test5)
I can continue writing:

```
location /test3 {
    index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /test3/index.php;
    expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
}
```

etc. But May be there is some standart way not to dublicate config?
Like

```
location /(subfolder) {
    index index.html index.php; ## Allow a static html file to be shown first
    try_files $uri $uri/ /(subfolder)/index.php;
    expires 30d; ## Assume all files are cachable
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You almost got it on your last location statement, just replace `/(subfolder)` to `/`, and the subfolder string on the line with `try_files` to `/$uri/index.php` instead of `/(subfolder)/index.php`:

```
location / {
  index index.html index.php;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /$uri/index.php;
  expires 30d;
}
```